# Why are BackColor and ForeColor Int32s in the Windows Forms Designer properties, but Drawing.Colors in the Designer code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I was expecting to be able to do something like:

```
public static class CustomColors
{
    Color CustomColor1 { get; set; } = Color.Black;
}

// In the designer:
form1.BackColor = CustomColors.CustomColor1;
```

This is in a C#, Windows Forms application.

However, I noticed that when using the designer in Visual Studio, the BackColor and ForeColor fields will only accept integers and have a color picker for you to choose from. If I want to use my CustomColors class and type in something like `CustomColors.CustomColor1`, or `System.Drawing.Color.Black`:

[image]

I get the following error:

> CustomColors.CustomColor1 is not a valid value for Int32.

However, selecting `Web` then `Black` in the designer properties window produces the following line of code in the designer:

`this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;`

I can type my static color into the designer code like this:

`this.BackColor = CustomColors.CustomColor1;`

but then the designer doesn't work (with the same error as above).

Defining static ints doesn't work either - I tried this:

```
public static class CustomColors
{
   Int32 CustomColor1 { get; set; } = Color.Black.ToArgb();
}
```

This isn't just the Windows Forms controls - I tried making a user control with a browsable Color property, and I'm also limited to the color picker in the designer.

Can anyone explain this? What's the designer doing here? How is it translating between ints and Colors, and why can't I use my own?

Comment: PropertyGrid uses a TypeConverter to convert from the grid entry to the underlying type.  It is ColorConverter for the BackColor property, it only recognizes strings.  It first tries to match it against one of the known colors (like "Red"), next try to interpret it as a number.  The latter fails.  At no point does it consider your class, it only sees the string.  You'd have to make your own BackColor property with its own [TypeConverter].

Comment: To rephrase, what you type into the property grid is not code.

Comment: @HansPassant That perfectly answers my question, thanks! I just wanted to understand why. Feel free to post it as a full answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: You may find this article helpful. [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx).

Comment: See the existing [ColorConverter Class - System.Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colorconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) for a sample implementation.